# Find if survey data is consistent across years by participant in dplyr in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have data which looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
ID = c(rep(c("ABC123", "BCD234", "CDE345", "DEF456", "EFG567", "FGH678", "GHI891", "HIJ910", "IJK101", "JKL011"),2)),
eth = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2),
nzdep = c(4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3),
sex =  c("M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M"),
Year = c(rep("Y1", 10), rep("Y2", 10)))
```

This is survey data, for the same people, in different years. The ID is a unique ID per person, and the Year tells us which year the survey was completed. What I want to know, is whether the same ID answered the same question the same way in both years.

I have tried something like this:

```
dems <- df %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(dep_dif = ifelse(nzdep = nzdep, 1, 0),
     sex_dif = ifelse(sex = sex, 1, 0),
     eth_dif = ifelse(eth = eth, 1, 0))
```

This doesn't work, but I was thinking something along these lines.

My desired output would be:

```
dems <- data.frame(
ID = c(rep(c("ABC123", "BCD234", "CDE345", "DEF456", "EFG567", "FGH678", "GHI891", "HIJ910", "IJK101", "JKL011"),2)),
eth = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2),
nzdep = c(4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3),
sex = c("M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M"),
Year = c(rep("Y1", 10), rep("Y2", 10)),
eth_dif = c(rep(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),2)),
dep_dif = c(rep(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),2)),
sex_dif = c(rep(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),2)))
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need `unique` value equal to one

```
df%>%group_by(ID)%>%dplyr::mutate( ifelse(length(unique(nzdep))==1, 1, 0),
+                                    sex_dif = ifelse(length(unique(sex))==1, 1, 0),
+                                    eth_dif = ifelse(length(unique(eth))==1, 1, 0))
# A tibble: 20 x 8
# Groups:   ID [10]
       ID   eth nzdep    sex   Year `ifelse(length(unique(nzdep)) == 1, 1, 0)` sex_dif eth_dif
   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <fctr> <fctr>                                      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 ABC123     1     4      M     Y1                                          1       0       1
 2 BCD234     2     3      M     Y1                                          1       1       0
 3 CDE345     2     3      F     Y1                                          1       0       0
 4 DEF456     3     2      F     Y1                                          0       0       1
 5 EFG567     1     4      M     Y1                                          1       1       1
 6 FGH678     1     4      M     Y1                                          0       0       0
 7 GHI891     4     1      F     Y1                                          1       1       1
 8 HIJ910     4     1      F     Y1                                          1       0       1
 9 IJK101     3     2      M     Y1                                          1       0       1
10 JKL011     3     2      M     Y1                                          0       1       0
11 ABC123     1     4      F     Y2                                          1       0       1
12 BCD234     4     3      M     Y2                                          1       1       0
13 CDE345     1     3      M     Y2                                          1       0       0
14 DEF456     3     4      M     Y2                                          0       0       1
15 EFG567     1     4      M     Y2                                          1       1       1
16 FGH678     3     2      F     Y2                                          0       0       0
17 GHI891     4     1      F     Y2                                          1       1       1
18 HIJ910     4     1      M     Y2                                          1       0       1
19 IJK101     3     2      F     Y2                                          1       0       1
20 JKL011     2     3      M     Y2                                          0       1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do this with `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate_at(2:4, funs(dif = as.integer(.[Year == "Y1"] == .[Year == "Y2"])))
# A tibble: 20 x 8
# Groups:   ID [10]
#   ID       eth nzdep sex   Year  eth_dif nzdep_dif sex_dif
#   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>   <int>     <int>   <int>
# 1 ABC123     1     4 M     Y1          1         1       0
# 2 BCD234     2     3 M     Y1          0         1       1
# 3 CDE345     2     3 F     Y1          0         1       0
# 4 DEF456     3     2 F     Y1          1         0       0
# 5 EFG567     1     4 M     Y1          1         1       1
# 6 FGH678     1     4 M     Y1          0         0       0
# 7 GHI891     4     1 F     Y1          1         1       1
# 8 HIJ910     4     1 F     Y1          1         1       0
# 9 IJK101     3     2 M     Y1          1         1       0
#10 JKL011     3     2 M     Y1          0         0       1
#11 ABC123     1     4 F     Y2          1         1       0
#12 BCD234     4     3 M     Y2          0         1       1
#13 CDE345     1     3 M     Y2          0         1       0
#14 DEF456     3     4 M     Y2          1         0       0
#15 EFG567     1     4 M     Y2          1         1       1
#16 FGH678     3     2 F     Y2          0         0       0
#17 GHI891     4     1 F     Y2          1         1       1
#18 HIJ910     4     1 M     Y2          1         1       0
#19 IJK101     3     2 F     Y2          1         1       0
#20 JKL011     2     3 M     Y2          0         0       1
```

---

If the 'ID' is already ordered a `base R` option would be

```
df[paste0(names(df)[2:4], "_dif")] <- +(Reduce(`==`, split(df[2:4], df$Year)))
```